# sessionStorage not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

On page load I am storing a value in the session and again getting back after loading the page. But IE and Chrome are not returning back the session storage value.

On Firefox it is working as expected.

Here is the code:

```
<select id="myDropDownList" name="myDropDownList" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">twoCode</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myDropDownList').change(function() {
    var dropVal = $(this).val();
    sessionStorage.setItem("SelectedItem", dropVal);
    location.reload();
});

$("#mydropdownlist").val(sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem"));
```

Comment: use localStorage

Comment: I have changed to localStorage instead of sessionStorage but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing to the proper capitalization seems to fix it for my test on Chrome.

Change to:

```
 $("#myDropDownList").val(sessionStorage.getItem("SelectedItem"));
```

Expanding on why a bit. Looks like JQuery uses appropriate browser methods if available, and those tend to be case sensitive. I guess it isn't in Firefox though.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for help